# For each item in a Vuex Store, assign a score (based on a calculation), then sort all by score

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to get my head around how to best implement the following requirements into a Vuex (vue.js) application.

I'll try and keep it as simple as possible, what i'm looking to achieve is something similar to Hacker News site. Therefore application will need to calculate a score for each item (post) based on a calculation/algorithm. The score is determined by a combination of likes and the date it was created on. Therefore the scores are constantly updating (until a designated time period expires) therefore it the score is not stored in a data source but calculated by the app.

So my main question is, how best to go about implementing this for a Vuex application?

I have set up a Vuex store of posts (i've called each article a 'post') and I'm able to display all the posts in a list. So now i've have two main objectives:

- Assign a score to the posts (articles)
- Filter the posts results list by their scores.

I've done some research and the consensus feels like it would be best to keep the 'score' separate from the 'posts' store (not added to the 'posts' array).

The following code works fine, however feels verbose. Would it be better to move any of these functions to 'getters/mutations/actions'?

Please note: for this examples i've simplified the calculation/algorithm to 'likes' total plus 'comments' total, obviously the final algorithm is more complicated to work like hacker news.

```
<div>
  <button @click="postFilterKey = 'all'"><button>
  <button @click="postFilterKey = 'orderByScore'"><button>
</div>

<div v-for="post in filterPosts" v-bind:key="post.value">
  <p>Title: {{ post.title }}</p> 
  <p>Total Likes: {{ post.likes }}</p>
  <p>Total Comments: {{ post.comments }}</p>
  <p>Score: {{ post.comments | getScore(post.likes) }}</p>
</div>
```

```
computed: {
   ...mapState(["posts"]),
   filterPosts () {
     return this[this.postFilterKey]
   },
   all () {
     return this.posts;
   },
   orderByScore (){
     return this.posts.sort((b,a) =>
        this.calculateScore(a.totalComments, a.totalLike) - 
        this.calculateScore(b.totalComments, b.totalLike));
   },

methods: {
    calculateScore(totalComments, totalLikes) {
     let score = totalComments + totalLikes
     return score;
   },
}

filters: {
    getScore(totalComments, totalLikes) {
     let score = totalComments + totalLikes
     return score;
   },
}
```

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Maybe moving the `orderByScore` into a Vuex Getter would be okay? Then the ordered posts are kind of linked directly to the store. If you have working code, your refactoring is largely up to personal preference. I would personally go down the OO route of "what makes sense to live in the store?" and put the things most closely tied to the store in there. Anything too reliant on outside variables might not make sense to live in the store. Then again, that's just my preference and you might want to implement it differently.

Comment: Honestly, looking at your computed/methods/filters, all of it would make sense to live in the Vuex store as Getters.

Comment: Also, moving things into the store will mean you're not duplicating code if you need the logic in more than one component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, what you have will work fine, and there is nothing wrong with it, per se.

There are a couple issues with your current code that could be improved:

1. If you want to reuse the score anywhere else in your app that is not a direct child of this component, you will have to duplicate the `getScore()` function in that component which is harder to maintain.
2. Every time the page is rendered the `getScore()` function gets re-run once for every post in the list, and every time the user sorts the list, the `calculateScore()` and `getScore()` functions will re-run once for each item in the list, which is not very efficient.

One solution, as you alluded to, is to put these functions in the store as getters. This would solve both issues I listed above by:

1. Keeping your code DRY by keeping these functions in one location.
2. Running these functions as vuex getters will cache the results so that they only re-run if the state they are dependent on changes.

An example of what your getter property in your store may look like is:

```
getters: {
  postsWithScore: state => {
    return state.posts.map(post => {
      return {
        ...post,
        score: post.comments + post.likes,
    });
  }
}
```

See the vuex docs for more info: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: Your example was exactly what i was looking for, feels much cleaner (dryer) now! Thank you Devin!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving the score calculation to a getter. It feels like a piece of the business model, why should it be fixed in a component that's merely using it? From what I recall, vuex's getter have some caching built in, so there's  performance gain as well.

PS. Dynamic scoring base on time has its downsides btw. You probably don't wanna move the items around while user looks at them, but what about pagination? When user goes to the next page and your score changes in the meantime, then the continuity of the list is broke. Anyhow, it's just kinda UX concern I believe.